# customizing xml plugin sonarqube

Tags: java, json, xml, sonarqube

I am trying to customize xml plugin of Sonarqube to check Json syntax. My logic to check Json is working fine when I test it by providing a particular xml file. But when in plugin,it fails.

Here is my code inside the package org.sonar.plugins.xml.checks

```
      @Rule(
              key = "JsonCheck",
              name = "Json should be in correct format",
                      description = "This rule is for checking Json",
              priority = Priority.CRITICAL,
              tags = {"convention"})
            @BelongsToProfile(title = CheckRepository.SONAR_WAY_PROFILE_NAME, priority = Priority.CRITICAL)    
        @SqaleSubCharacteristic(RulesDefinition.SubCharacteristics.READABILITY)
    @SqaleConstantRemediation("1min")
    @RuleTemplate
    public class JsonCheck extends AbstractXmlCheck {
        @RuleProperty(key = "Json", description = "This rule is for checking Json", type = "TEXT")
        private static final String MESSAGE = "Please provide valid Json";



        @Override
          public void validate(XmlSourceCode xmlSourceCode) {
            setWebSourceCode(xmlSourceCode);

            Document document = getWebSourceCode().getDocument(true);

            if (document.getDocumentElement() != null) {
                validateJson(document.getDocumentElement(),document);
                }
        }


        private void validateJson(Node node, Document document)
        {
            String JsonString = getJsonString(document);
            boolean Json = ValidateJson(JsonString);
            if (Json == false) {
                  createViolation(getWebSourceCode().getLineForNode(node), String.format(MESSAGE));
                }
        }   
private String getJsonString(Document document)
        {
             XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
             XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

             XPathExpression expr;
            try {
                expr = xpath.compile("//Payload");
                return (String) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);

            } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "";
            }


        }
        private boolean ValidateJson(String JsonString)
        {
            boolean bool;
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            try {
                gson.fromJson(JsonString, Object.class);
                bool =  true;
                return bool;
            } catch(com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException ex) { 
                bool =  false;
                return bool;
            }
        }

    }
```

I am not able to understand how this plugin is iterating through all xml files in the project based on which I should change my logic? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Why would you do that? There's already a [JSON plugin](https://github.com/racodond/sonar-json-plugin)

Comment: Because I have  json string inside a tag in my xml files whose syntax I want to detect and based on that I want to raise the voilation.. I guess Json plugin is for scanning json files against some rules. Please correct me if I am wrong or can I achieve this with Json plugin?

Comment: You're right; you can't achieve that with the JSON plugin